# How to augment data from REST api

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios

In my React app I am consuming a REST API. I have multiple end points that return a certain object, e.g. a Person:

- `/api/persons`: returns a list of persons
- `/api/persons/:id`: returns a specific person
- `/api/cars/:id`: returns a person in `owner` property of the car

In each case, I have an object representing a person and I have now found the need to add functionality to these objects, e.g. I want to add a `displayName()` function that concats the first and last name and the ID.
In good OOP fashion, I don't want to repeat that code wherever I need the display name. Instead I would like to add that function to the returned object.

Is there an accepted default way to do so? Like letting it know which classes to deserialize to? Or should I simply manually transform the data after fetching it?

Answer (score 2):

This prototype method can be used against any object that has the properties "firstName" and "lastName":

```
Object.prototype.displayName = function() {
    if(this.firstName && this.lastName)
    {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
    }
    return ""
}
```

Usage:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
}

person.displayName() // "John Doe"
```

Obviously, if you defined `Person` as a class you could also extend it using `Person.prototype.displayName`, rather than creating a prototype of `Object`.

Comment: Is it really good practice to add new functions to the Object prototype?

Comment: Well, prototype is faster and more memory efficient than creating the function for every new instance of a class. The function will only be created once. I don't see any downside of using it, apart maybe the risk of overriding an existing function (but it seems like a remote possibility).

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `class Person` with a constructor which accepts an argument of the POJO (plain old JavaScript object) type you receive from the API and declare the class methods. Then on your HTTP response handler, you should map the objects to instances of the `Person` class.

```
// declare the class
class Person {
  constructor(person) {
    this.name = person.name;
    this.age = person.age;
  }

  displayName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

// convert the plain objects to instances of the Person class
const people = apiResponse.people.map(person => new Person(person));
```

Comment: That's what I mean by "manually transforming the data after fetching it". Obviously, this is possible, but I don't like writing this mapping code manually.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply assign a new object with necessary prototype to the received objects from the API calls.

```js
var apiData = [{_id: 317, name: "John", lastname: "Doe"},
               {_id: 562, name: "Fred", lastname: "Lee"}],
    proto   = {displayName: function(){
                              var dn = `${this.name} ${this.lastname} ${this._id}`;
                              console.log(dn);
                              return dn;
                            }},
    data    = apiData.map(d => Object.assign(Object.create(proto),d));
data.forEach(d => d.displayName());
```